# Generating Debug Packages using Wix

Tags: .net, msbuild, wix, nant, pdb-files

My question is regarding the best way to generate Debug msi packages using wix.

Below is an explanation of my scenario:

1. The build server (MSBuild + NAnt) builds the code in Release and Debug configurations separately and pleases the binaries in bin\Release and bin\Debug folders.
2. The Wix msi's take the binaries from bin\Release and create the required packages.

**Now we want to create, packages with debug binaries as well (debug binaries + pdbs).**

**What is the best way to generate the new debug packages using Wix ?**

A. Should I create new wix projects which pick binaries and pdbs from bin\Debug? The NAnt script would need to modified to not build release packages during debug build.

B. Can we modify the existing package code to some how know that it is debug build and conditionally take binaries and pdb's from new location.

Please let me know!

Much Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in a serious discussion on whether this should be done. I once worked at a company where a handful of developers wanted this done but we resisted saying that we build installers for production.  Did we miss something?  I've never had anyone else ask for this in my career.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/04/11/making-debugging-easier-source-indexing-and-symbol-server.aspx

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - Even I think we should not be generating packages for debug builds but I have never worked on setting up builds and was not aware of **what is the best way to keep debug binaries and symbols together**. I am now thinking of having a single folder \Bin for both debug and release builds. Build script will first trigger the debug build, create packages & copy the pdb's & dbg package to debug package folder. After this build script will clear the \Bin folder, trigger the release build, create release packages and copy them to release package folder. Is this a good approach ?

Comment: Thanks Cristopher. Saw your link after posting above comment. I am going through your link and it looks like answer to my question. Still would request your view on my above comment\ question.

Comment: My concern is it adds complexity to the installer, decreases the likelihood of the release installer being tested, decreases build performance.   Whatever you decide, test thoroughly and proceed as you like.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter-Thanks for your input. They will be really helpful in deciding the final approach.